# Dynamically adding jquery into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamically-generated

Apologies, I know there are a number of questions along the same lines and they've helped me a lot but I'm still falling at the final hurdle.

I'm trying to dynamically add some jQuery into a div using this:

```
function displayPage(position,page){
    // position arrives looking something like '#pageW20' - ignore quotes
    // page arrives looking something like 'pages/benefits.html' - ignore quotes
    var pos = position.substring(1); // New variable without the '#' that appears in the first character of position
    var myDiv = document.getElementById(pos); // Find the div, typically equates to a div id similar to 'pageW20'
    var str = "<script type='text/javascript'>";
/*  Build the script which typically looks like this:-
<script type='text/javascript'> $( "#pageB15" ).load( "pages/benefits.html", function(){openLetter()}); </script> 
*/
    str += '$( ' + '"' + position + '"' +' ).load(' + page + ', function(){openLetter()})';
    str += '<';
    str += '/script>';
    alert(str); // Works to here, alert churns out expected output.
    //$('"' + position + '"').append(str); // Tried this, end up with syntax error
    myDiv.appendChild(str); // This gives Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
}
```

The last two lines show the errors I'm getting trying 2 different methods. Any clues.
Thanks appreciate your interest.

Update: Here's what I get in my console at the alert() stage which is what I was hoping for -

```
<script type='text/javascript'>$( "#pageW20" ).load("pages/work.html", function(){openLetter()})</script>
```

**Update: Now solved,** thanks @gaetano. My code now looks like:

```
function displayPage(position,page){
    var pos = position.substring(1); 
    var myDiv = document.getElementById(pos); 
    myDiv.innerHTML=""; // Remove existing div content
/*  Build the script which typically looks like this:-
<script type='text/javascript'> $( "#pageB15" ).load( "pages/benefits.html", function(){openLetter()}); </script> 
*/
    var str = '$( ' + '"' + position + '"' +' ).load(' + page + ', function(){openLetter()});';
    console.log(str); 
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.text = str;
    myDiv.appendChild(s);
}
```

Comment: show code than I can help you

Comment: Why are you trying to add jQuery to a div dynamically? Can you not just write your script outright and have it execute using the divs as selectors? Also, HTML code would be appreciated, it gives a better context to the problem you are experiencing

Comment: This is a really weird way of doing anything in Javascript. I can only assume this is your X/Y solution for adding content to a dynamically created element, in which case you should look in to delegated event handlers

Comment: Thanks both, I'm building a page from XML data, one element of which has a boolean flag that gets interpreted as 'if true' put some javascript in the div, else put raw HTML. The bulk of my elements are just straight HTML, only a handful give a link to a sub page that gets dynamically loaded into the. The particular Q I was asking relates to the adding the script into the div instead of raw html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot understand why you are trying to create and append a script on the fly like described in the comments.

The error you get is:

myDiv.appendChild(str);

But [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) requires as first parameter a node.

So if you need to continue in this direction you have to create a script node element and after you can append it to the html like in my example:

```js
function displayPage(position, page) {
  var pos = position.substring(1); // New variable without the '#' that appears in the first character of position
  var myDiv = document.getElementById(pos); // Find the div, typically equates to a div id similar to 'pageW20'
  var str = '$( ' + '"' + position + '"' + ' ).load("' + page + '", function(){openLetter()})';
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.text = str;
  myDiv.appendChild(s);
}

displayPage('_XXX', 'page');

console.log(document.getElementById('XXX').outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="XXX"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @gaetanoM, not there yet but think I'm going to get there. My script is appearing where it should now. I'll post back when I'm there.

Comment: Cracked it, thanks @gaetano, I had a couple of errors, 1) the div I was trying to load this into was not empty before my function call so I needed to clear it first, then 2) a couple of minor syntax code errors. Your code worked just fine! Thanks so much.

Comment: @RogerW  In order to empty the div you may use: myDiv.innerHTML = "";  Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The `str` variable you're passing isn't a Node, it's a String. Try first using:

```
var line = document.createElement("p");
line.innerHTML = str;
myDiv.appendChild(line);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ish I'm at least getting past the error stage now. May now be able to track down why the javascript / jquery isn't showing quite correctly. I'll post back.

Comment: `script` element can also be used: `var scriptElement = document.createElement("script");` Link: [html dom object : Script](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_script.asp)

Comment: Well, there was a minor syntax error in my string script building, now corrected. The javascript is now appearing correctly in my div but doesn't get called when I click the link that is supposed to activate it. FYI I have a load of these divs, most are built with straight HTML each with links to display them, these work. The function displayPage I'm showing is for the handful of divs that should containing the javascript I'm showing above, these don't. Is it a question of the page not having registered there's new javascript on there?